# How to remove splash screen on meteor

Tags: cordova, mobile, meteor

How can I remove the default splash screen for the Cordova integration with MeteorJS? I can't seem to find anything about it on the [Meteor Docs](http://docs.meteor.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found out how to do it.

In mobile-config.js:

```
App.setPreference('SplashScreen', 'CDVSplashScreen')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to remove splashscreen but for replace default splashscreen you need to set something like this:

```
App.launchScreens({
  'iphone': path,
  'iphone_2x': path,
  'iphone5': path,
  'iphone6': path,
  'iphone6p_portrait': path,
  'iphone6p_landscape': path,
  'ipad_portrait': path,
  'ipad_portrait_2x': path,
  'ipad_landscape': path,
  'ipad_landscape_2x': path,
  'android_ldpi_portrait': path,
  'android_mdpi_portrait': path,
  'android_hdpi_portrait': path,
  'android_xhdpi_portrait': path
})
```

in mobile-config.js in project root

for more information you can check: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/App-Splash-Screen-Sizes

Comment: Thanks, however this does not really answer my question.